# Поиск метасимвола в строке как обычного

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Есть строки

```
234АА|asd
23*АА|asd
233ААasd
```

Мне нужно с помощью `regexp_substr` вытащить именно подстроку вида `'^[[:digit:]]{3}[[:alpha:]]{2}'`, но только тех, где следующий за шаблоном символ будет вертикальная черта. Другими словами, из приведенных трех строк вернуть результат, отличный от NULL, должна только первая строка. Однако, я не могу просто добавить конструкцию вида `[|]` к шаблону. Как быть?

Comment: Ответ очень простой: символ `|` это специальный символ, используемый для поиска альтернатив. Специальные символы должны быть экранированы. Ваше выражение должно быть таким `^[[:digit:]]{3}[[:alpha:]]{2}\|`

Comment: @AlexR. На самом деле, может у меня уже ночью ум за разум заходил, но я действительно не смог нагуглить такой простой ответ, поэтому его можно запостить именно как ответ, не смотря на простоту.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cимвол `|` это специальный символ, используемый для поиска альтернатив.

Специальные символы должны быть экранированы символов `\`.

Результирующее выражение `^[[:digit:]]{3}[[:alpha:]]{2}\|`.